# bootstrap grid, text too far apart

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to make a webpage responsive by stacking the nested grid when viewport is xs. It works in xs by stacking those two grids, but the text inside of those grid got too distanced from each other when view in sm and larger, I gotta be doing something wrong here and struggled for hours, please help, really appreciated! Reputation too low to post direct image, please see pic uploaded links.

http://i68.tinypic.com/ru1dvm.png

http://i67.tinypic.com/157iqli.jpg

---

```
     <div class="row row-content">

             <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                        <h3>Alberto Somayya</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                        <h3><small>Executive Chef</small></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world.!</em></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is bootstrap version? 3 doesn't support nested grids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way with what you're trying to achieve.  You want the name and the occupation title to be both h3 so try just making a span class for the title:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h3>Alberto Somayya <span class="split-text"><small>Executive Chef</small></span></h3>
<p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world.!</p>
      </div>
      </div>
```

and then using a media query to create a breaking point so the text goes from inline to block:

```
.split-text {display:block;}
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width:768px) {
 .split-text{display:inline;}
}
```

It's much simpler.  Here's a fiddle showing it at work http://jsfiddle.net/czc7x7w8/8/

Comment: Havent learnt about the media query yet. It seems to be working in that fiddle page. Will try to incorporate it into the project later. much appreciated Jake!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem that may be causing this is that your number of columns falls too short in **sm** and above. For **xs** you have the full 12 in each row, which is the base rule for Bootstrap grid system.

Try changing the `col-sm-` value from 3 to 6, or make an empty column on either side and make it fill the entire row.

Each row should be **12 total**. You can go over that, but you should still count the column numbers to be relevant to 12 (using col-sm-12 and two col-sm-6's in the same `.row` is fine, for the two 6's go side by side, filling that other 12.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand there are 12 cols in each row. The goal I am trying to accomplish is to have Name stack above Title without disrupting the original setting in when viewing in sm and up (which the Title sits next to the Name closely, instead of too far apart.) Jake's solution is perfect for this matter. Thanks for all you helps!